# How can I use PHP Simple HTML DOM to get the contents of a tags attribute?

Tags: php, simpledom

I want to get the contents of the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag. Here is the code I'm using:

```
require_once( 'simple_html_dom.php');

$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $webpage);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);  
$str = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);  

if( $str )
{
    $html= str_get_html($str);
    $img = $html->find('img', 0); // get the first image on the page
    $src = $img->src; // get the contents of the img src - but it doesn't seem to work
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing a first `'` in the first line!!!

Comment: I just left it out when removing unnecessary code. It's actually there in my code. I tried following the documentation page for simple dom, but I can't get it to work. I AM, however, able to get the contents of various tags. I just can't capture only the attribute.

Comment: Oh okay, is it possible to dump the output of `$str` and check if it is the desired output?

Comment: I have successfully been able to do `$tag = $html->find('h1',0);` so the problem must be with with the last two lines of code from above.

Comment: Oh thats good! But what's the difference? Both are right na? You used a `img` tag in your question and now `h1` in your answer.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that I can use the above code to get an `h1`, but it won't work if I try to get an `<img>` `src` attribute.

Comment: But there was no difference right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$webpage ="http://www.santabanta.com";

$html = file_get_html($webpage);

foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    echo $element->src . '<br>'; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You are missing a first `'` in the first line!!!

Replace:

```
require_once( simple_html_dom.php');
```

With:

```
require_once( 'simple_html_dom.php');
```

Comment: Check the first line again not missing a first ' in the first line.

Comment: @AbidHussain I gave the answer long back and the OP has replied back about that he's corrected it. We are discussing about that and mind removing that downvote, whoever voted? Will be updating the answer soon!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP provided DOM parser to get 1st image's src like this:

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $webpage);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);  
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);  

if( !empty($html) ) {
   $doc = new DOMDocument;
   libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
   $doc->loadHTML($html);
   #echo $doc->saveHTML();
   $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
   $src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");
   echo "src=" . $src . "\n";
}
```